# Texas Hold’em pot

Tags: poker-strategy

Texas hold’em: say there are three fives in the flop no one has any plays at all. Does the pot go to the player with the highest card in their hand? Or is the pot split to all of the players?

Comment: I'm going to close this one as it's been answered before. Please see the linked answer above!

Comment: the winning hand is the best five cards, the pot does not split